# When to get an aliya for a Bar Mitzvah?

Tags: minhag, chabad, rosh-chodesh-new-month, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

According to the new ["Annotated Edition"](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=16091&st=bar+mitzvah) of the Siddur Tehillas Hashem, a Bar Mitzvah bachur should get his first aliya either on Shabbos Mincha time, Monday, Thursday, or Rosh Chodesh.

I assume that the source is from [Sefer Haminhagim](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/64.htm) where it says either Monday, Thursday or Shabbos Mincha time. It does **not** mention Rosh Chodesh.

What is the source of note in the Tehillas Hashem siddur that one could get his first aliya on Rosh Chodesh?

Comment: Many have the minhag of the first aliyah being the first opportunity after the exact day. Perhaps that is what is meant so that if the first opportunity is Rosh Chodesh, it should be taken.

Comment: @sabbahillel except Shabbos

Comment: In our shul the boy will lein the full Parsha as well as the haftarah. If that was the first opportunity, then it is the first time he gets an aliyah.

Answer (score 4):

The second line of your source in Sefer HaminHagim mentions Rosh Chodesh

Comment: But that's talking about the father saying Baruch Shepetarani - which doesn't necessarily have to be at the same time as the bar mitzvah boy's first aliyah.

Comment: More so, it says "not necessarily on Shabbos". But one can say it on Shabbos. One, however, shouldn't get their aliya on Shabbos morning.